# Will an enderman teleport if pushed into a hole / void?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing the famous Skyblock survival map and I have a noisy enderman playing around. I have to walk looking at my feet to avoid him becoming hostile. I was wondering if it's possible to push him into the Void, or if he'll just teleport to safety.

Does the enderman need to be on his feet to teleport or can it while in midair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Endermen won't teleport to avoid falling. Otherwise common Endermen XP farm designs in the End wouldn't work.